# Security of "command" in .ssh/authorized_keys

Tags: ssh, security

Let's say `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` contains

```
command="/home/me/bin/debug.sh",restrict ssh-rsa <X-PUBLIC-KEY>
```

and `/home/me/bin/debug.sh` contains:

```
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
  "scp -t /tmp/exact_path.txt")
    scp -t /tmp/exact_path.txt
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Access denied"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Intention I guess is clear - allow holder of X-PUBLIC-KEY to upload file exactly to one place "/tmp/exact_path.txt" and nothing else. (especially to disallow uploading stuff to `~/.ssh/` directory)

What is worst that can happen if "X-PUBLIC-KEY" falls into bad hands?
Is there a way for malicious user to use "X-PUBLIC-KEY" to achieve something more than intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless there is any kind of vulnerability in the `ssh` program itself, which allows circumventing this restriction (which is unlikely), the most they can do is upload a large file and fill the partition on which `/tmp` resides.